# How do I 'destroy' a sprite with a timer or stopwatch? (TechSmart)

Tags: python

I already destroyed sprites in previous lines, and coded a timer, but now it won't work.
[time check for 3 secs so the screen will change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAL4U.jpg)

I tried to use the same method, I deleted some things, changed previous lines, but the sprites will not delete within the timer.
[using the same method to destroy two sprites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvWiF.png)

Comment: Please, edit your question to include your code along with the text, properly formatted. Also, tagging the specific library you are using will help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.